# Adding to signature list from ROI list does not work?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying out QGIS with SCP, but I've run into some problems

First of all, my setup is as follows:
**QGIS version 2.10.1-Pisa**
on Mac **OSX Yosemite 10.10.5**
compiled and running against

- qt 4.8.6
- GDAL/OGR 1.11.2
- GEOS 3.4.2
- PostgreSQL 9.4.4
- QWT 6.0.2
- QScintilla2 2.9
- SpatiaLite 4.2.0
- PROJ.4 491

I'm following the tutorials found at the following URL: https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tutorials.html

My problems begin in the section on creating ROIs. The first issue (though I didn't notice it at first), is that when I create an ROI, it does not add it to the signature list despite "add sig. list" being checked! Not only that, but I don't seem to be able to create an ROI with the automatic region growing algorithm. When I try to do so, it gives me an error of the form:

> Error [29]: Edge error. Reduce the ROI width or draw a ROI manually (recommended installation of GDAL >= 1.10)

I worked around this by simply manually inputting the rest of the ROIs, and continued on with the tutorial, but it wasn't very long before I ran into the final problem, which is that I am unable to add the ROIs to the signature list at all. I've tried running QGIS from the command line, selecting an ROI, and hitting the add to sig list button, and it produces the following warning:

> Warning 1: Line 4: Attribute value should be single or double quoted. Going on, but this is invalid XML that might be rejected in future versions.

Since I am unable to get my ROIs added to the signature list, I am unsure of how to continue.